# How to render deleted item from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Render empty space when clicking the delete button. I have no idea, but `arr.find` render only 1-st item, no matter which button to press, there will always be the first element. `arr.filter` render empty list.

**reducer:**

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    name: action.name,
                    age: action.age
                }
            ];

        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            return  [
                ...state,
                state.filter(index => index !== action.id),
            ];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**render in App.js:**

```
function ListOfUsers() {
        const listItems = users.map(function (value, index) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <li key={index}>{value.name}, {value.age}</li>
                    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ITEM', id:index })}
                            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        Удалить
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <ul>{listItems}</ul>
        );
    }
```

**state looks like:**

```
const initialState = [
     {
        name: 'Theodore Roosevelt',
        age: 56
    },
];

export default initialState;
```

Comment: Hi, what is the issue you're having exactly ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be pushing the data to an array, and from there filtering it and deleting it ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for bed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt understand how working `filter`. Rework with more familiar `concat` & `slice`. If somebody tok me what wrong with `filter` and why he is not work i should be grateful

**successful**

```
return  [
                ...state.slice(0, action.id).concat(state.slice(action.id + 1))
            ];
```

Answer (score 1):

## Don't add your whole state when you need to delete

Do not spread the state out if you're removing a piece. Just spread out the results of your "delete" function.

```
case 'DELETE_ITEM':
  return  [
    ...state.filter(index => index !== action.id),
  ];
```

Comment: I do like you say, but it doesnt working. Logic is right, reducer gets right action.type and action.id. He is work and dont work sametime